# Disappearing controls in WPF

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have the an existing WPF xaml layout to which I added a stackview with a label and button. However, after adding it, the "columns" and "Layout columns" treeviews disappear when running the application. Here is the xaml for the form:

```
<UserControl xmlns:my="clr-namespace:MyNamespace.Controls.LayoutEditors.OrderableList"  x:Class="MyNamespace.Controls.LayoutEditors.LayoutColumnsEditor"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="832" d:DesignWidth="595"
         >
<Grid Name="Grid">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="110" />
            <RowDefinition Height="5" />                
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid Name="gridLabels">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <Label Style="{StaticResource SubHeaderLabel}" Content="Properties" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" />
                <StackPanel Margin="0 5"  Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Label Content="Layout Name:" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" Width="120"  />
                    <TextBox Width="488" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Name="EditLayoutName" LostKeyboardFocus="TextBoxLayoutNameLostFocus" MaxLength="50" />
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Label Content="Description:" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" Width="120" />
                    <TextBox Height="50" Name="EditDescription" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"  Width="483" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" />
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                    <Label Content="Search for Columns:" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" Width="120"></Label>
                    <TextBox Height="50" Name="txtColumnName" Width="200" TextWrapping="NoWrap" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" TextChanged="txtColumnName_TextChanged"></TextBox>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Row="2" Name="gridColumns">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="300" MinWidth="40" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="7" />
            <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="40" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid Background="White">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="20" />
                <RowDefinition />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Label Grid.Row="0" Content="Columns:" Height="21" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" Name="labelColumns" VerticalAlignment="Top" Style="{StaticResource SubHeaderLabel}" />
            <telerik:RadTreeView Background="White" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" FontSize="11" Grid.Row="1" Name="TreeColumns" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" IsDragDropEnabled="False" IsTextSearchEnabled="True" ItemDoubleClick="TreeColumnsItemDoubleClick" IsEditable="True" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" />
        </Grid>
        <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="gridSpiliter" Width="7" Background="#FF4D6798" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ResizeDirection="Columns" BorderBrush="#FF021E4B" BorderThickness="1" />
        <Grid Grid.Column="2" Name="TileViewGrid" MinWidth="40">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="174*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="114*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="20" />
                <RowDefinition />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Label Content="Layout Columns:" Height="21" Name="labelLauoutColumns" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Style="{StaticResource SubHeaderLabel}" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
            <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                <my:OrderableList x:Name="ListLayoutColumns" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="White" />
            </ScrollViewer>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
 </UserControl>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the elements add the `Grid.Column` and `Grid.Row` values.  For instance:

```
<Label Content="Layout Columns:" Height="21" Name="labelLauoutColumns" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Style="{StaticResource SubHeaderLabel}" 
    Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
    Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"
/>
```

In fact, make sure that you do this for **each** UI element that will be contained in the grid. This way you can be sure that the controls are *exactly* where you want them.

HTH!